# Importing a .proto file into another

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I have an apparently simple issue. I have two .proto files, let's say a.proto and b.proto, and b.proto imports a.proto:

b.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package My.Example.Proj;
import "a.proto";
message B {
    ....
    A fromTheOther = 1;
}
```

a.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package My.Example.Proj;
message A {
   ....
}
```

---

In my proto.targets I have the command that compiles the .proto files to C#:

> "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)......\protobuf\protoc-3.9.2\bin\protoc.exe" --csharp_out=$(SolutionDir)\generated_csharp\ --proto_path=%(RootDir)%(Directory) --error_format="msvs" %(Filename).proto

This command produces indeed A.cs and B.cs, but when I try to use these files in another C# project, I see this compilation error in B.cs (the one that is supposed to use the type A from the other proto):

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'A' does not exist in the namespace 'My.Example.Proj' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*
> at this line in B.cs: `public global::My.Example.Proj.A FromTheOther`

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, though I tried several *import* options, with the same result.

Comment: "are you missing an assembly reference?"? If you're using Visual Studio right click on `Dependencies` in your project where you're getting the error and click on `Add project reference`. A dialog should open, on the left hand select `Projects` and check the checkbox next to `My.Example.Proj` (or whatever the name of your project containing `A.cs` and `B.cs` is)

Comment: Are you including both files (A.cs and B.cs) in the project?

Comment: @MindSwipe that was my first reaction too, but it wasn't the issue

Answer (score 2):

The generated `B.cs` will not contain the types which `b.proto` references via `import`.

Compiling `B.cs` will therefore require `A.cs` to be included too.

If you already are including both files, verify that they they are both being generated successfully by `protoc` and you are including the latest versions.

Comment: Indeed, I was caught on the wrong foot, thinking that my 'import' statement in .proto caused something fishy, but it looked like I simply didn't have both A.cs and B.cs in my DLL. Thanks all for the support.